# Groovy ava.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No such DSL method 'sendToSlack' found among steps

Tags: groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I am trying to build a pipeline with Groovy, everything works fine but when I try to call a method inside an each loop it cannot see it.

(I have very basic knowledge of groovy).
Here is the error I get:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No such DSL method 'sendToSlack' found among steps [ansiblePlaybook, ansibleVault, archive, bat, build, catchError, checkout, deleteDir, dir, dockerFingerprintFrom, dockerFingerprintRun, dockerNode, ec2, echo, emailext, emailextrecipients, envVarsForTool, error, fileExists, findFiles, getContext, git, httpRequest, input, isUnix, jiraComment, jiraIssueSelector, jiraSearch, junit, library, libraryResource, load, mail, milestone, node, nodesByLabel, parallel, powershell, properties, publishHTML, pwd, readFile, readJSON, readManifest, readMavenPom, readProperties, readTrusted, readYaml, resolveScm, retry, script, setGitHubPullRequestStatus, sh, sha1, slackSend, sleep, sshagent, stage, stash, step, svn, tee, timeout, tm, tool, touch, unarchive, unstash, unzip, validateDeclarativePipeline, waitForQualityGate, waitUntil, withContext, withCredentials, withDockerContainer, withDockerRegistry, withDockerServer, withEnv, wrap, writeFile, writeJSON, writeMavenPom, writeYaml, ws, zip] or symbols [absolute, agent, all, allOf, allure, always, ant, antFromApache, antOutcome, antTarget, any, anyOf, apiToken, architecture, archiveArtifacts, artifactManager, attach, authorizationMatrix, batchFile, bitbucket, booleanParam, branch, brokenBuildSuspects, brokenTestsSuspects, buildButton, buildDiscarder, buildParameter, bzt, caseInsensitive, caseSensitive, certificate, changelog, changeset, checkoutToSubdirectory, checkstyle, choice, choiceParam, clock, cloud, command, configFile, configFileProvider, copyArtifacts, credentials, cron, c
```

And Here is the loop I am trying to call:

```
def slack = load 'jenkins-pipeline/utils.groovy'

  stage 'Automation local tests'
    slack.sendToSlack('good', "Starting UI tests")
    partners.each {
      utils.sendToSlack("=============> Start UI test for ${it.name} <=============");
      cmd = "node_modules/.bin/protractor node_modules/ct-ui-automation/conf.js --params.browsers='chrome_headless' --baseUrl='${part.url}?version=${verJson}' --directConnect --specs='node_modules/ct-ui-automation/ui_tests/gt/common/specs/e2e_spec/*/*'' --params.buildNumber='${verJson}' --params.environment='external-dev'";
      def res = sh(returnStdout: true, script: cmd)
      slack.sendToSlack("=============> END UI test for ${it.name}, ${it.url} <=============");
    }
```

How can I call my `slack.sendToSlack` method inside the `partners.each` ?

The contents of utils:

```
void sendToSlack(colorCode, teamMessage) {
  try {
    slackSend([
      channel: '#somechannel',
      color: colorCode,
      message: teamMessage,
      teamDomain: 'domain',
      token: 'token'
    ])
  }
  catch(e) {
    echo 'sendToSlack() error: ' + e.message;
  }
}

return this;
```

Comment: What's in the `utils.groovy` file?

Comment: @StephenKing is a function containing utils functions (the slack send message one)

Comment: Yes, but maybe it is not declared correctly